# Why is my slideshow erratic? (Timing issues)

Tags: javascript, timer

I have been tinkering with pasting an image into a browser through extracting the data via the clipboard...

I have managed to create a reasonable slideshow script working, but the problem is that the timing between slides is erratic... I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Current behavior:

1. An image can be pasted into the slideshow from the clipboard. New images will appear as a tile below the main view.
2. Clicking a tile selects a tile for display in the main view.
3. Double clicking the tile removes the tile from the tile board.
4. Once a tile is selected it automatically is inserted into the slideshow and the slideshow starts.
5. clicking the main view screen will pause the slideshow. Clicking it again will resume it.

The problem is, the timing between multiple images is erratic and won't keep at the 2000ms I want between images...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body id="ourDoc" contenteditable="true" onpaste="handlepaste(event);">
<div class="slideshow_area" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: black; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; background-size: cover;">
    <div class="noImg" style="width: 130px; height: 25px; margin: 25% auto; color: white;">No Image Selected</div>
    <div class="pause" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin-top: -176px; left: 0px; position: relative; color: white; font-size: 96px; text-align: center;" onclick="($(this).css('opacity')==1)?pauseSlideShow():($('.pause').css('opacity',0)||playSlideShow());">||</div>

</div>
<div class="thumbnail_area" style="width: 300px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;"></div>

    <script src="./jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
function handlepaste(evt) {
    var cbData;
    // get Clipboard data
    if (evt.clipboardData) {
        cbData = evt.clipboardData;
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        cbData = window.clipboardData;      
    }
    // Stop image being pasted.
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    imgArr = cbData.getData('text/html').split(" "); // Grab data for image
    imgSrc = imgArr[1].split("=")[1]; // get source of image
    imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(/\"/g, "");

    newImgNode = '<div class="tile" style="height: 80px; width: 80px; outline: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); background-image:url('+imgSrc+'); background-size: cover; float: left; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;" onDblClick="$(this).remove();" onClick="$(this).toggleClass(\'sel\'); $(\'.noImg\').css(\'opacity\', 1-($(\'.sel\').length>0));($(\'.sel\').length>0)?playSlideShow():stopSlideShow();"></div>';

    $(".thumbnail_area").append(newImgNode);
    delete newImgNode;
}
tileIndex = null;
function playSlideShow(){
    if($(".pause").css("opacity") < 1){
        numTiles = $(".sel").length;
        (numTiles>0)&&$(".pause").css("opacity",0);
        (numTiles!=null)&&(tileIndex = tileIndex || 0);
        imgVal = $(".sel:eq("+tileIndex+")").css("backgroundImage");
        $(".slideshow_area").css("background-image",imgVal);
        delete imgVal;
        tileIndex++;
        tileIndex%=numTiles;
        (numTiles<1)&&(clearTimeout("playIt")||stopSlideShow());
        delete numTiles;
        if($(".sel").length>0){
            setTimeout("playSlideShow();",2000);
        }
    }
}
function pauseSlideShow(){
    $(".pause").css("opacity",1);
}
function stopSlideShow(){
    $(".slideshow_area").css("background-image","none");
    $(".pause").css("opacity",0);
    $(".noImg").css("opacity",1);   
}

$(".pause").css("opacity", +($(".slideshow_area").hasClass("play")));
</script>
<style>
    .sel {outline: 5px solid orange !important;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any clues what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Better use setInterval to regulary change the image. With both you don't know when your callback will be actually executed because when timeout / interval triggers, the only thing that happen is that your callback is appended to javascript task queue but currently executing task (if any) is not stopped. Your callback awaits that function to end to be executed.

Using interval the same happens, but you start counting from last time interval triggered. With timeout you start counting when your code is actually execued, which is your timeout plus random time that javascript loop took to reach your callback and execute it (first reason of your erratic behaviour).

A probable second reason is that, in below code, you are trying to *clear a string* ("playIt") like if it were a timeout:

```
function playSlideShow(){
    if($(".pause").css("opacity") < 1){
        ...
        (numTiles<1)&&(clearTimeout("playIt")||stopSlideShow());
        ...
        if($(".sel").length>0){
            setTimeout("playSlideShow();",2000);
        }
    }
}
```

clearTimeout() needs a variable holding a timeout object to effectively clear it. See [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) about it.

You probably would do something like:

```
var myTimeout;
function playSlideShow(){
    if($(".pause").css("opacity") < 1){
        ...
        (numTiles<1)&&(clearTimeout(myTimeout)||stopSlideShow());
        ...
        if($(".sel").length>0){
            myTimeout = setTimeout("playSlideShow();",2000);
        }
    }
}
```

(not sure if it works. But at least this way timeout definition and clearing is correct).